# Android Studio: Referencing a "java-6-compiled-jar" causes UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, exception, jar, reference, android-studio

Whenever I put my jar file that was compiled using language level 6 or 7 in the Android Studio's 'libs' folder and try to deploy the application to the device, I get the following exception:

```
Unexpected Error
Local path doesn't exist. Local path doesn't exist. The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version
```

Strangely, if I remove my jar and put another jar file (say joda-time-x.jar) there, everything works just fine.

Also

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

in the build.gradle does not help.

Comment: I think that jar file is corrupted somehow. The error message is relevant to it having a bad file signature. It's not the same error you get from a Java class file version incompatibility (which usually looks something like "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0").

Comment: The jar is created using the Intellij artifact as instructed in the Intellij blogs. can't imagine what could be wrong with that.

Comment: You can run jar -tf on it to see if the jar utility can understand it. If not, it might be useful to examine the file and see what's in it. Sometimes in cases like that the file is actually a text error message or log because something screwy happened during the build. Or you may be able to identify its file type and figure it out.

Comment: jar -tf shows all the class files as well as their locations. Can't see any errors at all.